# getExternalFilesDir(null) gives java.io.IOException: Read-only file system

Tags: android, save

I'm trying to write a text file in the root folder of my app with the below code

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "values.txt");

        file.createNewFile();
```

All i am getting is java.io.IOException: Read-only file system

i have uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the manifest file.

How can i fix this issue ?

I have tried it on an emulator and a nexus 7 and cant seem to find what is causing the issue.

I see a lot of answers talking about remounting my file system but i can expect everyone that downloads the app to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> getExternalFilesDir(null)

Will return, The path of the directory holding application files on external storage. Returns null if external storage is not currently mounted so it could not ensure the path exists; you will need to call this method again when it is available.

So In your case we don't know whether external storage is mounted or not, but as you want to put file on root folder of your app. just use [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29). It will store your file in internal storage where your application files are stored.

Comment: I need to be able to copy the text file to a pc so must use external storage

Comment: @Skeith - So just check whether your external storage is not mounted on PC when you try to run your application.

Comment: @Skeith - Mostly on `settings>storage>unmount USB storage` or just unplug usb from pc when you try to run your application.

Comment: Log what getExternalFilesDir() is actually returning.  If it returns null, you may be trying to create your file in the root directory of the phone, which is of course not writable by you (or likely by anyone during normal operation).